# sleep function doesnt work in lua. help pls

Tags: lua

```
function sleep(n)
    os.execute("sleep " .. tonumber(n))
  end

sleep(2)
print("hi")
```

This is my code and the terminal returns this,

'sleep' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own system independent `sleep()` more like...

```
function sleep(sec)
local se = os.time() + sec
while os.time() < se do
  io.write('\b','-')
  io.write('\b','\\')
  io.write('\b','|')
  io.write('\b','/')
  io.write('\b','-')
end
io.write('\b\n')
end
```

...but Lua will loop afap including warming up CPU and max fan speed.

Maybe it is better to wait for user acceptance?

```
function pause(text)
local text = text or 'Press Enter '
io.write(text)
io.read()
end
```

That dont cost any CPU Time.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
function sleep (s) 
    local sec = tonumber(os.clock() + s); 
    while (os.clock()<sec) do 
    end 
end
sleep(2)
print("hi")
```

you can use this code for Windows:

```
function sleep(n)
    os.execute('powershell "Sleep ' .. tonumber(n) .. '"' )
end
```

or use ping:

```
function sleep(n)
  os.execute("ping -n " .. tonumber(n+1) .. " localhost > NUL") 
end
```

Comment: `tostring(n+1)`